# How to convert Perl generated string(Object) into JSON using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, json, perl

I created a REST API using Laravel (Lumen). Basically I'm taking some values from database and need to do some functions. Here's the problem.
There's a field called web_data in my result set. It's Perl code. This is how it looks when I query the database using normal SQL editor like phpmyadmin and workbench.

```
{"caption" => "Genes (Comprehensive set from GENCODE 26)","colour_key" => "[biotype]","default" => {"MultiBottom" => "collapsed_label","MultiTop" => "gene_label","alignsliceviewbottom" => "as_collapsed_label","contigviewbottom" => "transcript_label","contigviewtop" => "gene_label","cytoview" => "gene_label"},"key" => "ensembl","label_key" => "[biotype]","multi_name" => "GENCODE 26 Comprehensive gene set","name" => "Comprehensive Gene Annotations from GENCODE 26"}
```

It's very clear and nothing wrong. But when I get the same result via my REST API, I'm getting the following output. It has many "\" symbols. Here's that output.

```
{\"caption\" => \"Genes (Comprehensive set from GENCODE 26)\",\"colour_key\" => \"[biotype]\",\"default\" => {\"MultiBottom\" => \"collapsed_label\",\"MultiTop\" => \"gene_label\",\"alignsliceviewbottom\" => \"as_collapsed_label\",\"contigviewbottom\" => \"transcript_label\",\"contigviewtop\" => \"gene_label\",\"cytoview\" => \"gene_label\"},\"key\" => \"ensembl\",\"label_key\" => \"[biotype]\",\"multi_name\" => \"GENCODE 26 Comprehensive gene set\",\"name\" => \"Comprehensive Gene Annotations from GENCODE 26\"}
```

Can you please tell me what's the reason for this? Is this an issue with PHP or something like that ?

And also I have another issue. This is Perl code containing "=>" symbols to seperate values. I need to convert this into a JSON object using PHP. Is that possible ? 
Need to convert like following object.

```
{ "caption" : "Genes (Comprehensive set from GENCODE 26)", "colour_key" : "[biotype]", "default" : { "MultiBottom" : "collapsed_label" ...
```

This is the php code i'm using to create the REST output using SQL data.

```
public function testDualDatabaseConnection()
{
    $testGene = DB::connection('mysql2')->select('select a.analysis_id, logic_name, ad.description, ad.display_label, ad.web_data FROM ( select distinct(analysis_id) as analysis_id from gene ) as a join analysis on (a.analysis_id = analysis.analysis_id) join analysis_description as ad on (analysis.analysis_id = ad.analysis_id) where ad.displayable =  :wow1', ['wow1' => "1"]);
    return response()->json($testGene);
}
```

And also this is the full JSON output i'm getting via REST API.
https://gist.github.com/chanakaDe/0d1e5916d8bc788bb101afa9b92dc9cd

In this response, you can see "web_data", that's also the part I need to convert to JSON again.

Comment: We need more information. We need to see the code that generates the JSON. And we need to know how you are viewing the REST API result.

Comment: @ChanakaDeSilva — Edit your question and use the formatting features provided. Posting large chunks of code into a comment leaves an unreadable mess.

Comment: @DaveCross Please check. I edited the question.

Comment: You're asking to convert Perl *code* into JSON!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Not sure where that escaping happens (if you can, give some more details)

But, try to replace `=>` with `:` and `\"` with `"` and you'll have yourself a valid json.

```
$string = '{\"caption\" => \"Genes (Comprehensive set from GENCODE 26)\",\"colour_key\" => \"[biotype]\",\"default\" => {\"MultiBottom\" => \"collapsed_label\",\"MultiTop\" => \"gene_label\",\"alignsliceviewbottom\" => \"as_collapsed_label\",\"contigviewbottom\" => \"transcript_label\",\"contigviewtop\" => \"gene_label\",\"cytoview\" => \"gene_label\"},\"key\" => \"ensembl\",\"label_key\" => \"[biotype]\",\"multi_name\" => \"GENCODE 26 Comprehensive gene set\",\"name\" => \"Comprehensive Gene Annotations from GENCODE 26\"}';

$string = str_replace('\"','"', $string);
$string = str_replace('=>',':', $string);
$json = json_decode($string, true);
print_r($json);
```

You can check it out here: https://3v4l.org/UBmGA

---

Apparently this answer got more hate than i'd expect. Nevertheless, it did help OP and i'm sticking by it. In the end, this is what SO stands for.

I would like to know though... why so many downvotes? I *do* take constructive criticism well and would like to know how to improve future answers.

Comment: You also need to remove trailing commas at the end of lists. In Perl those are allowed, in json they are not.

Comment: @simbabque, the datastructure OP provided doesn't have lists. But if it did, a simple `$string = str_replace(',]',']', $string);` would do the job. And no, i'm not gonna regex a json string ;). I usually don't overcomplicate problems

Comment: @simbabque, The Perl code was surely produced by Data::Dumper, which won't create those commas. There's a *slew* of other issues, however.

Comment: @AlexTartan that's not a list, it's an array reference. Anything in Perl that is separated by commas is a list. Some of those happen to be array or hash references. You can put trailing commas everywhere. They create empty elements and those just get removed. Ikegami is right, it's probably Data::Dumper output. I think there's a flag to turn them on though.

Answer (score 2):

If on the off chance you really do have

```
{\"caption\" => \"Genes ...\", ...}
```

Then you have a JSON fragment, and the first you thing you need to do is turn it into a complete JSON document so it can be decoded.

```
$json_fragment_from_api = '{\"caption\" => \"Genes ...\", ...}';
$json_from_api = '{"result":"' . $json_fragment_from_api . '"}';
$response = json_decode($json_from_api, true);
$perl_code = $response["result"];
```

---

That said, I think it's far more likely that you only showed a portion of your actual input. You're far more likely to have received something that looks more like

```
{ "result": "{\"caption\" => \"Genes ...\", ...}" }
```

Since you already have a complete JSON document, simply start by decoding it.

```
$json_from_api = '{ "result": "{\"caption\" => \"Genes ...\", ...}" }';
$response = json_decode($json_from_api, true);
$perl_code = $response["result"];
```

---

At this point, you have the value from the database.

```
{"caption" => "Genes ...", ...}
```

That value is Perl code. More specifically, it's surely Perl code that was produced by Data::Dumper. This is going to be hard to convert into JSON.

You could use the following, but it won't handle everything:

```
$desired_json = str_replace(' =>', ':', $perl_code);
```

Here are some things it won't handle:

- Undefined values
- Strings containing `=>`
- Strings containing `$`
- Strings containing `@`
- Strings containing non-ASCII or some non-printable characters.

As shown here:

```
$ perl -e'
   use feature qw( say );
   use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );
   local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
   local $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
   local $Data::Dumper::Indent = 0;
   say(Dumper({ x => undef }));
   say(Dumper({ x => " => " }));
   say(Dumper({ x => q{$} }));
   say(Dumper({ x => q{@} }));
   say(Dumper({ x => "\x7F" }));
'
{"x" => undef}      # Gives {"x": undef}  instead of {"x": null}
{"x" => " => "}     # Gives {"x": ": "}   instead of {"x": " => "}
{"x" => "\$"}       # Gives {"x": "\$"}   instead of {"x": "$"}
{"x" => "\@"}       # Gives {"x": "\@"}   instead of {"x": "@"}
{"x" => "\177"}     # Gives {"x": "\177"} instead of {"x": "\u007f"}
```

Comment: you might want to put that `str_replace` before the `json_decode`. It will fail to decode that string if there are "=>" in it. more precisely, `json_last_error_msg()` will return "Syntax error". 
which kinda leaves you with what i wrote...

Comment: @Alex Tartan, No, that would be wrong. The OP is starting with a JSON string. The fact that the string contains `=>` is of no consequence. `"{\"caption\" => \"Genes ...\", ...}"` will properly decode.

Comment: please see https://3v4l.org/WiDli It's an online platform that executes php code. I've made a snippet to demonstrate this. Don't get me wrong, my piece of code is not a generic converter. It's just supposed to work with the type of data OP provided. To make a proper converter, yes, a lot more cases need to be accounted.

Comment: Re "*Re "notice i didn't change $db_string!*", Actually, you did. If you do `echo $db_string`, you will see it's different than what the OP posted. Here's a [proper test](https://3v4l.org/Tun7q). As you can see, both solutions give the correct output for the provided input. However, yours will fail for so many other valid inputs!